# Parsing XML in VB .Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to extract some info from an XML file generated by another application, this is a slighlty cut down version for clarity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--IE2C Current Input-->
<RSLogix5000Content SchemaRevision="1.0" SoftwareRevision="19.01" >
<Controller Use="Context" Name="MAIN">
<AddOnInstructionDefinitions Use="Context">
<EncodedData EncryptionConfig="2">
<Description>
<![CDATA[IE2C Current Input]]>
</Description>
<RevisionNote>
<![CDATA[Initial Revision]]>
</RevisionNote>
zNti6YvCK0McoTr4NZK1iyGdEAkM0sxvRC35nnfg/Gd6x+f1lAbsW0PwA4f9TfqHs3MmOQ9OhS9...</EncodedData>
</AddOnInstructionDefinitions>
</Controller>
</RSLogix5000Content>
```

I can successfully return the EncryptionConfig value (2) using the following code:

```
Dim xml As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(filepath)
xmlNav = xml.CreateNavigator()
xmlNI = xmlNav.Select("//EncodedData")
While (xmlNI.MoveNext())
    If IsNumeric(xmlNI.Current.GetAttribute("EncryptionConfig", "")) Then
        encryptionconfig = xmlNI.Current.GetAttribute("EncryptionConfig", "")
    Else
        encryptionconfig = 0
    End If
End While
xmlNI = Nothing
xmlNav = Nothing
xml = Nothing
```

The problem is that I also need to return just the 'zNti6YvCK0McoTr4NZK1iyGdEAkM0...' value too. Everything I have tried so far returns it along with the Description and RevisionNote values which I don't want.

**Update**

This is the final code allowing for unencoded files and some file versions that don't contain the EncryptionConfig attribute:

```
Dim b64text As String = ""
Dim encryptionconfig As Integer = 0
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(filepath)
Dim node = xml.Descendants("EncodedData")(0)
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    b64text = node.Nodes().OfType(Of XText)().First().Value.Trim()
    If node.Attribute("EncryptionConfig") IsNot Nothing Then
        encryptionconfig = node.Attribute("EncryptionConfig").Value
    End If
Else
    Label6.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label6.Text = "File is not encoded"
End If
node = Nothing
xml = Nothing
```

Comment: Is this valid XML? The 'zNti6YvC...' part looks weird to me. It is not an attribute nor a child?

Comment: It's actually base64 encoded XML that the application adds into the main XML. I guess in that respect it's not valid which is probably why I'm having difficulty just extracting that string as it has no attribute name. What I'm actually trying to do is pull the base64 string, decrypt it and insert the resulting XML back into the main XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the type of all nodes in `<EncodedData>` for text. A simple way would be to use linq2xml, the `OfType` method and the [`XText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.linq.xtext.aspx) type:

**Example:**

```
Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
            <!--IE2C Current Input-->
            <RSLogix5000Content SchemaRevision="1.0" SoftwareRevision="19.01" >
            <Controller Use="Context" Name="MAIN">
            <AddOnInstructionDefinitions Use="Context">
            <EncodedData EncryptionConfig="2">
            <Description>
            <![CDATA[IE2C Current Input]]>
            </Description>
            <RevisionNote>
            <![CDATA[Initial Revision]]>
            </RevisionNote>
            zNti6YvCK0McoTr4NZK1iyGdEAkM0sxvRC35nnfg/Gd6x+f1lAbsW0PwA4f9TfqHs3MmOQ9OhS9...</EncodedData>
            </AddOnInstructionDefinitions>
            </Controller>
            </RSLogix5000Content>

Dim node = xml.Descendants("EncodedData")(0)
Dim data = node.Nodes().OfType(Of XText)().First().Value.Trim() ' is zNti6YvCK0McoTr4NZK1iyGdEAkM0sxvRC35nnfg/Gd6x+f1lAbsW0PwA4f9TfqHs3MmOQ9OhS9... '
Dim config = node.Attribute("EncryptionConfig").Value ' is 2 '
```